# Recover a 4D Rotor in geometric algebra from rotated vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, rotations, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

This question is closely related to [angle and plane of rotation in 3D geometric algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922021/angle-and-plane-of-rotation-in-3d-geometric-algebra). For example, Doran & Lasenby already showed a proof for the 3D case, but things are a bit different in 4D.

In general, a rotor in 4D consists of a scalar, 6 bivectors and one four-vector (in 3D, a rotor is just composed of a scalar and 3 bivectors). Then,  assume that we already know two 4-dimensional vectors and one is a rotated version of the other. How is it possible to derive a similar expression for the rotor? does it exist? If so, could a general expression for n dimensions be obtained?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312044/472818

Comment: The solution was provided in https://www.researchgate.net/post/4D_rotations_and_rotors_can_a_general_expression_be_derived Edited 20-jan-22: the right solution was updated in researchgate.